# Which log4net is compatible with .net version 4 and windows azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, .net-4.0, log4net, log4net-configuration

I just downloaded log4net but got four different folders in bin below

```
cli , mono , net ,net-cp
```

> which version is compatible with .net version 4 and windows azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- cli      ECMA CLI 1.0 compatible version
- mono     Version for mono
- net      General Microsoft .net version
- net-cp   .Net compact version

In your can you can use the net version, azure is running the latest Microsoft runtime, the cli of net-cp version will probably also work.